# Cursor is going at the start automatically in contentEditable

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am creating a website builder. For Text edit, I m using contentEditable and to capture its state I m using the onInput event. but I don't know why every time I type something cursor goes to start.

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-cherry-8qwrfq?file=/src/Introduction.jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you CHANGE the state for each click and you display it. Cursor is reset when state is updated
replace `onInput` with `onBlur`